# Objective tools for monitoring WCF APIs for latency, failures, and breakdowns?

Tags: wcf, monitoring, observation

We have numerous APIs developed using WCF and are seeking recommendations for objective tools capable of monitoring them for latency, failures, and breakdowns.

Our requirements include:

- Real-time monitoring of latency metrics for each API endpoint.
- Alerting mechanisms to notify us of failures or performance degradation.
- Detailed breakdown analysis to identify bottlenecks or issues within our WCF APIs.

We prefer tools that are widely used and have a proven track record in monitoring WCF services effectively.

If you have experience with such tools or can recommend objective solutions based on your expertise, we'd greatly appreciate your insights.

Thank you for your assistance!"

Comment: You can use most monitoring tools. Application Insights, or use OpenTelemetry (and should your exporters as you'd like). You probably won't find a solution that is directly plug-and-play in that regard, though it is not too difficult with some custom code to inject those things in your services (and propagate the traceIds for correlation). (I have done this with MSMQ wcf services and it works like a charm.)

Comment: Recommendation requests are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stack overflow, but this may be on topic for [softwarerecs.se].  Before posting there, check out their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336).

Comment: You can try Fiddler. At the same time WCF has its own run logs, which should also help.